# Timer every hour but starting from 1 minute

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I would like to create a countdown timer for my resource. An example for this I took from [Quasimodo's clone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3741589/quasimodos-clone) answer of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179899/countdown-timer-every-hour-but-on-30-minute-marks).

From the code, I took some elements, since I only need minutes and seconds. And I don't need a 30 minute mark.

The code works great, but unlike the author of the question, I need the start to start and end at 1 minute of the next hour.

The changes that I made did not lead to the desired result:

```
secsRemaining = 3600 - (time.getUTCMinutes()+1)%60 * 60 - time.getUTCSeconds(),
```

and

```
mins = (Math.floor(secsRemaining / 60)+60),
```

This gave a result, but not the one that is needed. When the time on the clock becomes 00 minutes, then the code becomes 60 minutes and 00+ seconds. I need, for example, at 14:00:59 the timer has the values ​​00:01, and when 14:01:01 the timer has the values ​​59:59.

Please let me know how it can be changed to achieve the desired result. Perhaps you have a link to solutions. I couldn't find it on the Internet.

Code I am using:

```js
var byId = document.getElementById.bind(document);

function updateTime() {
  var time = new Date(),
    secsRemaining = 3600 - (time.getUTCMinutes()) % 60 * 60 - time.getUTCSeconds(),
    mins = (Math.floor(secsRemaining / 60)),
    secs = secsRemaining % 60;
  byId('min-part').textContent = mins;
  byId('sec-part').textContent = secs;
  setTimeout(updateTime, 1000 - (new Date()).getUTCMilliseconds()).toLocaleString();
}
updateTime();
```

```html
<div>Time left before update: <span id="min-part"></span>:<span id="sec-part"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it

- Generating a date at the next hour and 1 minutes
- Calculating the number of millisecond between the current date and the next date
- Display the time remaining

```js
const minutes = document.getElementById('minutes')
const seconds = document.getElementById('seconds')

setInterval(() => {
  const now = new Date()
  const nextHours = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), now.getHours() + 1, 1)
  const nbMilisec = (nextHours - now)

  const nbMinutes = parseInt((nbMilisec / 1000 / 60) % 60)
  const nbSeconds = parseInt((nbMilisec / 1000)  % 60)
  
  
  minutes.innerHTML = String(nbMinutes).padStart(2, '0')
  seconds.innerHTML = String(nbSeconds).padStart(2, '0')
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div id="time">
  Time left before update : <span id="minutes"></span> : <span id="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your decision! Good luck to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your needs, this should be the code you need:

```
var byId = document.getElementById.bind(document);

function updateTime()
{
  var
    time = new Date(),
    // You need an hour of countdown, so 30 becomes 60
    secsRemaining = 3600 - (time.getUTCMinutes()+60)%60 * 60 - time.getUTCSeconds(),
    // integer division
    // you want the timer to "end" at minute 1, so add 1 minute to the minutes counter
    mins = (Math.floor(secsRemaining / 60) + 1) % 60, 
    secs = secsRemaining % 60
  ;
  byId('min-total').textContent = secsRemaining;
  byId('min-part').textContent  = mins;
  byId('sec-part').textContent  = secs;

  // let's be sophisticated and get a fresh time object
  // to calculate the next seconds shift of the clock
  setTimeout( updateTime, 1000 - (new Date()).getUTCMilliseconds() );
}
updateTime();
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to complete my task. Good luck to you ;)